# Calendar Reminder

Tags: android, calendar

I have created Calendar reminder in android but is bug I am trying to fix:

> I want to set time to reminder : Scenario 1 : 10AM And Scenario 2 : 6PM

Whenever I create a reminder and set time it always get set for AM and not for PM how to configure the AM and PM filter I tried setting calendar AM PM format but that does not seems to work

Below is my code snippet:

```
private void setReminderToCalendar() {

    try {
        if (format.trim().toLowerCase().equals("am")) {
            calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
        } else {
            calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);
        }
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(hr));
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(min));
        calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, -2); // create reminder 2 hr ago
        insertReminderInCalendar(FindingVendorAndTimelineActivity.this, calendar);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void insertReminderInCalendar(Activity activity, Calendar cal) {

    Uri EVENTS_URI = Uri.parse(getCalendarUriBase(true) + "events");
    ContentResolver cr = activity.getContentResolver();
    TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();

    /** Inserting an event in calendar. */
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, 1);
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, "  Order Configured");
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, "You have schedule roti order today");
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.ALL_DAY, 0);
    // event starts at 0 minutes from now
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, cal.getTimeInMillis());
    // ends 60 minutes from now
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, cal.getTimeInMillis() + 2 * 60 * 1000);
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, timeZone.getID());
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.HAS_ALARM, 1);
    Uri event = cr.insert(EVENTS_URI, values);

    // Display event id.
    Toast.makeText(RotiApplication.getInstance(), "  scheduled order is been added to you calendar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    /** Adding reminder for event added. */
    Uri REMINDERS_URI = Uri.parse(getCalendarUriBase(true) + "reminders");
    values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.EVENT_ID, Long.parseLong(event.getLastPathSegment()));
    values.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD, CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD_ALERT);
    values.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.MINUTES, 10);
    cr.insert(REMINDERS_URI, values);
}
```

How to configure AM / PM filter in calendar event in Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(hr));

Using HOUR_OF_DAY sets time in 24 hour format (6 pm will be 18 hours). Using the HOUR_OF_DAY will make using am/pm useless. Use 24 hour format and leave setting am/pm manually. Calendar will automatically convert it in am/pm format.

Comment: oops minor mistake i thought and experimented with 24 hours but my line of code was not effecting it since i setted it twice , thx for striking me this point ! it worked !